# Unable to download zip file from server with %20 in it's name but when I copy the link from html it works fine

Tags: django

I am trying to figure out the exact issue but with little success. I have rendered a template containing the link for a file in media directory of my server. The filename has a space in it in the media directory and in the database this space has been replaced with %20 in the filename. I am fetching the filename from the database and passing it to the HTML template with the media url. When I check the rendered html, it has %20 and if I copy the link from the HTML and try to download the file, it is getting downloaded.

e.g.

The file in the HTML looks like : http://abc.domain.com/media/Demo%20Report.xlsx

The file in the media directory is "Demo Report.xlsx"

Comment: This is *percent encoding*. You can not use a space in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is [*percentage encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Not all characters can be used in a URL. Characters like `!`, `*`, `'`, and space are encoded with a percentage, followed by the code point of the character in hexadecimal characters. A space has a codepoint 32, hence it encodes to `%20`.

A lot of browsers however will automatically percent encode certain characters to query the resource properly.

If you need to urlencode data, you can make use of the [**`|urlencode`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode) to encode this properly. This is often necessary for the values of the *querystring*.

As a general rule of thumb, you want to prevent using spaces in the first place. Often it is better to work with an underscore, so `Demo_Report.xlsx`.